# How to use italics in R graph axis labels

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I have plotted the following graph:

```
visreg(MOD.1, xlab="Distance (m)", ylab="Sciurus vulgaris (Presence/Absence)",
       xvar="Distance")
```

And I would like to make just 'Sciurus vulgaris' in italics. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the example from the documentation of `?visreg` I think the functions `expression` and `italic` will give you what you need:

```
fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp,data=airquality)
visreg(fit, xlab="Distance (m)", 
       ylab=expression(italic("Sciurus vulgaris  ") (Presence/Absence)))
```

Output:

As you can see the y-axis label (only the "sciurus vulgaris") is in italics

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly speedy reply! I have managed to do that too but I can't get the '(Presence/Absence)' bit to stay in normal font. I have tried variants of this: 

ylab=expression(italic("Sciurus vulgaris")), "(Presence/Absence)"

But no luck!

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I misread the question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have altered all my graphs and they now read properly!