# How to italicise only a few words in only a few columns in ggplot2 using scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to create a graph showing the percentage of outbreaks due to each pathogen in my study. But I'd like to put some of the text in italics. This is the code so far...

```
etiology_graph_percent <- ggplot(data_long_etiology_percent)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Subregion),
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(color = "Subregion") +
  ylab("Percentage of Outbreaks") +
  xlab("Pathogen")+
  ylim(0,100)+
  My_Theme+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Campylobacter spp.", "Escherichia coli", "Salmonella spp.", "Cryptosporidium spp.", "Unknown", "Listeria monocytogenes", "Giardia", "Norovirus", "Coxiella burnetii", "Yersina pseudotuberculosis", "Brucella spp."))
```

For the labels, I'd like the spp. text not to be italics, e.g. *Campylobacter* spp., and obviously some would not be italic at all, for example "unknown".

I'm struggling to find a way to do this without changing the scale_x_discrete function!

Answer (score 0):

Try the italic function. Docs [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flextable/versions/0.7.0/topics/italic).
Also, this is possibly a [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213424/how-to-use-italics-in-r-graph-axis-labels).

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried both of these things and neither work